# Python: how to compute the number of shortest paths passing through one node?

Tags: python, networkx, shortest-path

Say that I have a regular network of `NxN` nodes. The shortest path between two nodes is the minimum number of hops required to reach one *target* node from a *source* node. Now, each shortest path passes through a number of nodes along the way.

My goal: for each node in the network, I want to count the number of shortest paths that pass through a specific node, and save that number in a `dict`.

In this little example, node B has 4 shortest paths passing through it:
`A -> B`, `A -> C`, `C -> B`, `C -> A`. **I want to be able to compute this number for each node in a generic graph.**
[image]

I know I could use the [nx.betweenness_centrality()](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.betweenness_centrality.html#id7), but this will give me a numerator (which is, for each node, what I want) divided by a denominator which stores all the possible shortest paths between two nodes. I have even accessed the source code but I wasn't able to figure out where the division is performed.

I know this is a wordy question but I had no other means to explain my problem. Thank you to anyone who will help.

**EDIT**

This is the source code for `nx.betweenness_centrality()`. My graph is undirected. It is unclear which line hosts the division I introduced above:

```
def betweenness_centrality(G, k=None, normalized=True, weight=None,
                           endpoints=False,
                           seed=None): #G is the graph

    betweenness = dict.fromkeys(G, 0.0)  
    if k is None:
        nodes = G
    else:
        random.seed(seed)
        nodes = random.sample(G.nodes(), k)
    for s in nodes:
        # single source shortest paths
        if weight is None:  # use BFS
            S, P, sigma = _single_source_shortest_path_basic(G, s)
        else:  # use Dijkstra's algorithm
            S, P, sigma = _single_source_dijkstra_path_basic(G, s, weight)
        # accumulation
        if endpoints:
            betweenness = _accumulate_endpoints(betweenness, S, P, sigma, s)
        else:
            betweenness = _accumulate_basic(betweenness, S, P, sigma, s)
    # rescaling
    betweenness = _rescale(betweenness, len(G),
                           normalized=normalized,
                           directed=G.is_directed(),
                           k=k)
    return betweenness #Returns a dict with the node ID as a key and the value
```

Comment: can you link to the source code or point to some modules/line numbers?

Comment: I will include the source code for better clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use `nx.all_pairs_shortest_path(G)`:

```
>>> G = nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_path([0,1,2])

>>> spaths = nx.all_pairs_shortest_path(G)
>>> spaths
{0: {0: [0], 1: [0, 1], 2: [0, 1, 2]},
 1: {0: [1, 0], 1: [1], 2: [1, 2]},
 2: {0: [2, 1, 0], 1: [2, 1], 2: [2]}}
```

Which finds you all the shortest paths between all pair of nodes in a graph (which is very expensive for large graphs). Then, the following code gives you the desired result:

```
def num_spaths(G):
    n_spaths = dict.fromkeys(G, 0.0)
    spaths = nx.all_pairs_shortest_path(G)

    for source in G:
        for path in spaths[source].values():
            for node in path[1:]: # ignore firs element (source == node)
                n_spaths[node] += 1 # this path passes through `node`

    return n_spaths
```

In your example:

```
>>> num_spaths(G)
{0: 2.0, 1: 4.0, 2: 2.0}
```

---

Additionally, if you could go inside the `all_pairs_shortest_path` code and sightly edit it to add a counter for shortest paths and

```
for node in path[1:]:
    n_spaths[node] += 1
```

this way, you would update the number of paths online at the same time you find one, rather than having to iterate over all them (as my code does) after all them are calculated.

EDIT: [in networkx (github)](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/blob/d7d906e1d16ef331da0bc1d149953e7532155acc/networkx/algorithms/shortest_paths/unweighted.py#L251), line 251 says:

```
paths[w]=paths[v]+[w]
```

You could potentially modify that function to update the number of shortest paths online (at the same time they are found) by passing `n_spath` as an argument to the modified function and updating it inside. Then calling the function would be as:

```
def num_spaths(G):
    n_spaths = dict.fromkeys(G, 0.0)
    for n in G:
        my_single_source_shortest_path(G, n, n_spaths)
    return n_spaths
```

and `n_spaths` would have the number of shortest path updated.

---

EDIT: The above only works if there is only 1 shortest path between A and B, as `nx.all_pairs_shortest_path` only returns one shortest paths per each node pair. Find bellow the brute force search for all posible shortest paths. I wouldn't recommend runing this in a large graph:

```
def bf_num_spaths(G):
    n_spaths = dict.fromkeys(G, 0.0)

    for source in G:
        for target in G:
            if source == target:
                continue
            for path in nx.all_shortest_paths(G, source, target):
                for node in path[1:]: # ignore firs element (source == node)
                    n_spaths[node] += 1 # this path passes through `node`

    return n_spaths
```

Comment: Can you tell me precisely which line in your solution avoids to count a path twice, given that the graph is undirected? If it does not do that, I could divide each dict value by 2.

Comment: @FC84 The code works now for undirected graphs, I was just updating it. See the edit, modifying `single_source_shortest_path` from `networkx` you could calculate the number of shortest paths online.

Comment: so based on your last addition, all I need to do is modify `all_pairs_shortest_path` and in my script, after having created `num_spaths`, just assign it to the modified function? Which is to say, in this case `num_spaths` would now be a dict and not a function, right?

Comment: @FC84 Yep sorry, updated the last example to avoid name conflicts. What you need to modify is the `single_source_shortest_path` (the function that `all_pairs_shortest_path` calls) in order to add a couple of lines and accept `n_spaths` as an input dictionary to modify it inplace.

Comment: Will this be computationally less expensive?

Comment: @FC84 the difference would be that you don't need to loop over all the shortest paths. So yes and no. It will be less expensive than looping over the shortest paths once they are calculated, however, this is something *irrelevant* compared to the time it takes to calculate all the shortest paths. So, in short, you can avoid this.

Comment: I have a question to ask. Can we turn the chat on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108843/discussion-between-fc84-and-imaluengo).

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to give pure algorithmic answer.

What if there are several shortest paths from `v_1` to `v_2` and some of them contain `v_mid`? If this case is counted as `1` for each `(v_1, v_2)` pair, you can use Floyd-Warshall algorithm. After its run, you have matrix with length of shortest paths. For each `u`, iterate over all `(v_1, v_2)` pairs and count `+1` if `D[v_1, u] + D[u, v_2] == D[v_1, v_2]`. It's O(n^3) and good for dense graphs.

I'm not sure but I think that it can be adjusted to count number of shortest paths.

Answer (score 1):

Without further access to the source code it is impossible to say for sure but my bet would be on:

```
S, P, sigma = _single_source_shortest_path_basic(G, s)
```

Or

```
betweenness = _rescale(betweenness, len(G),...
```

Rescale just *sounds* like it will contain a division.

Have you tried calling this function with `normalized=False`?

Comment: What do you exactly want when ask for further access to the source code?

Comment: Well the source code for the module itself is available (though a little hard to navigate). What I really meant is more information about your use case.

Comment: Well I haven't built one yet. I see your point, but I was not able to write anything. I would have if, within the source code, I'd have spotted the division I mentioned. `Normalize=False` seems not to be the solution, however.

Comment: _rescale has a factor of 1/2 thrown in for good measure...

def _rescale(betweenness, n, normalized, directed=False, k=None):
    ...
        if not directed:
            scale = 1.0 / 2.0
        else:
            scale = None
    if scale is not None:
        if k is not None:
            scale = scale * n / k
        for v in betweenness:
            betweenness[v] *= scale

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can modify the [Floyd-Warshall Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) to save the length of the path in another matrix. Pseudocode (based on wikipedia):

```
let dist and num be two |V| × |V| arrays of minimum
distances and lengths initialized to ∞ (infinity)

for each vertex v
   dist[v][v] ← 0
   num[v][v] ← 0

for each edge (u,v)
   dist[u][v] ← w(u,v)  // the weight of the edge (u,v)
   num[u][v] ← 1

for k from 1 to |V|
    for i from 1 to |V|
        for j from 1 to |V|
            if dist[i][j] > dist[i][k] + dist[k][j] 
                dist[i][j] ← dist[i][k] + dist[k][j]
                num[i][j] ← num[i][k] + num[k][j]
            end if
```