# Python: how to optimize the count of all possible shortest paths?

Tags: python, graph, graph-algorithm, networkx, shortest-path

In a `3x3` network I want to be able to determine all the shortest paths between any two nodes. Then, for each node in the network, I want to compute how many shortest paths pass through one specific node.

This requires using the `nx.all_shortest_paths(G,source,target)` function, which returns a `generator`. This is at variance from using the `nx.all_pairs_shortest_path(G)`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36552135/python-how-to-compute-the-number-of-shortest-paths-passing-through-one-node?answertab=active#tab-top). The difference is that in the former case the function computes **all** the shortest paths between any two nodes, while in the latter case it computes **only one** shortest path between the same pair of nodes.

Given that I need to consider **all** shortest paths, I have come up with the following script. This is how I generate the network I am working with:

```
import networkx as nx
N=3
G=nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N)
pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() )
labels = dict( ((i, j), i + (N-1-j) * N ) for i, j in G.nodes() )
nx.relabel_nodes(G,labels,False)
inds=labels.keys()
vals=labels.values()
inds.sort()
vals.sort()
pos2=dict(zip(vals,inds))
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos2, with_labels=False, node_size = 15)
```

And this is how I print all the shortest paths between any two nodes:

```
for n in G.nodes():
    for j in G.nodes():
        if (n!=j): #Self-loops are excluded
            gener=nx.all_shortest_paths(G,source=n,target=j)
            print('From node '+str(n)+' to '+str(j))
            for p in gener:
                print(p) 
            print('------')
```

The result is a path from node `x` to node `y` which only includes the nodes along the way. An excerpt of what I get is:

```
From node 0 to 2 #Only one path exists
[0, 1, 2] #Node 1 is passed through while going from node 0 to node 2
------
From node 0 to 4 #Two paths exist
[0, 1, 4] #Node 1 is passed through while going from node 0 to node 4
[0, 3, 4] #Node 3 is passed through while going from node 0 to node 4
------
...continues until all pairs of nodes are covered...
```

**My question: how could I amend the last code block to make sure that I know how many shortest paths, in total, pass through each node?** According to the excerpt outcome I've provided, node 1 is passed through 2 times, while node 3 is passed through 1 time (starting and ending node are excluded). This calculation needs to be carried out to the end to figure out the final number of paths through each node.

Comment: If you restrict the problem to 2D grid graphs, the number of shortest paths between any two points can be calculated analytically. If you're still interested in this problem, I can post the calculation as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest making a dict mapping each node to 0

```
counts = {}
for n in G.nodes(): counts[n] = 0
```

and then for each path you find -- you're already finding and printing them all -- iterate through the vertices on the path incrementing the appropriate values in your dict:

```
# ...
for p in gener:
    print(p)
    for v in p: counts[v] += 1
```

Comment: Well it works perfectly. I am wondering if there is any improvement to this procedure, especially because it looks like a demanding task when the size of the network increases. To give you an example, if timed for a network of `10x10` nodes, this procedure requires approx. 168 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

What you seek to compute is the unnormalized [betweenness centrality](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.betweenness_centrality.html#networkx.algorithms.centrality.betweenness_centrality).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality):

> The betweenness centrality is an indicator of a node's centrality in a network. It is equal to the number of shortest paths from all vertices to all others that pass through that node.

More generally, I suggest you have a look at all the [standard measures of centrality already in Networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/algorithms.centrality.html).

Comment: But doesn't this consider just one shortest path for each pair of nodes?

Comment: The quotation from Wikipedia in this answer is a misquotation. The betweenness centrality is not the total number of shortest paths from anywhere to anywhere. The b.c. of a node is the sum, over all pairs of nodes, of the fraction of shortest paths between them that go through the given node.

Comment: @FC84 All shortest paths. Edit: I think it seems that to answer your question: I want to be able to determine all the shortest paths between any two nodes. Then, for each node in the network, I want to compute how many shortest paths pass through one specific node.

Comment: Kikohs, you've edited your quotation but I'm afraid it's still wrong. I mean, what you've quoted does appear near the start of the Wikipedia article, but it just isn't correct. The formula found later in the article is correct.

Comment: By diving deeper into literature I've figured out that what I am looking for is not Betweenness Centrality, although the two metrics are similar.